# Deleted environment variable still works on Win10 cmd

Tags: gcc, environment-variables, windows-10, msys2

I wanted to update the gcc version on my Win10, but ran into problem with env vars.

The deleted environment variable `E:\\Mingw64\ming64\bin` still works in `cmd` .

Here's what I've tried:

The original environment variable of mingw was `E:\Mingw64\mingw64\bin`  , I deleted it from `%PATH` in the "Advanced System Settings", now my `%PATH` in `User Variables` and `System Variables` looks like these:

**User Variables**

[image: User variables]

**System Variables**

[image: System variables]

Then I restarted my cmd (and even my PC afterwards), run the command: `gcc --version` , it stills prompts the old version number;

Then I ran the command `where gcc` , it yields: `E:\Mingw64\mingw64\bin`  , which is the old mingw location;

What can I do to disable the old version of mingw64?

By the way, is there any recommended practice to manage gcc and gdb version on Windows? Is [msys2 recommended by Microsoft VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_prerequisites) a good idea?

Comment: `where gcc` gives me the old path of my gcc: `E:\\Mingw64\ming64\bin`

Comment: You said  "Then I restarted my cmd". Did you use a cmd started from windows menu?
Or did you restart VScode and used that cmd that opened in the Terminal?
VSCode does a lot to "restore" former sessions.
Maybe you should kill that terminal and open a real new one.

Comment: And yes, i think msys2 as compiler environment for VSCode is a real good thing....